# python lab tkinter giving error? _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-txt"

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I recently started learning python

I was doing a simple python mini-project speed typing GUI application

the compiler keeps giving errors as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\YCCE college\B-Odd 3rd Sem\Software Lab\Project(Application for typing speed test analysis)\First\speedtyping.py", line 96, in <module>
    hs_val = Label(root, txt= str(hs)+" WPM",width=12, fg="#03fcf8", bg="black", font="times 12")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3148, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-txt"
```

Code:

```
from os import error
from Tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(bg="Black")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("550x500")
window.withdraw()

hs_file = open('highscore.txt', '+r')
x=0

def game():
    global x
    if x==0:
        root.withdraw()
        x=x+1
    window.deiconify()
    def check_result():
        j=error=0
        answer=entry.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
        end = timer()
        time_taken=end-start
        
        if len(words[word])>=len(answer):
            error=len(words[word])-len(answer)
            for i in answer:
                if i == words[word]:
                    pass
                else:
                    error+=1
                j+=1
        elif len(words[word])<=len(answer):
            error=len(answer)-len(words[word])
            for i in words[word]:
                if i == answer[j]:
                    pass
                else:
                    error+=1
                j+=1
        wpm=len(answer)/5
        wpm= wpm-error
        wpm=int(wpm/(time_taken/60))
        hs_file.seek(0)
        line = int(hs_file.readline())
        if wpm>line:
            hs_file.seek(0)
            hs_file.write(str(wpm))
            result="Your Highscore is : "+str(wpm)+" WPM"
            messagebox.showinfo("Score", result)
        else:
            result="Your score is: "+str(wpm)+" WPM"
            messagebox.showinfo("Score",result)
    def finish():
        hs_file.close()
        window.destroy()
        root.destroy()
    
    words=["The world is beautiful.", "The kite is drastic."]
    word=random.randint(0, len(words)-1)

    x2= Label(window, text=words[word], bg='black', fg="white", height=7, width=47, font="times 15", wraplength=500)
    x2.place(x=15, y=10)

    x3=Button(window, text="Submit", font="times 20", bg="white", command=check_result)
    x3.place(x-220,y=350)

    entry = Text(window)
    entry.place(x=100, y=180, height=150, width=350)

    b2 = Button(window, text="Done", font="times 13", bg="#ffc003", width=12, command=finish)
    b2.place(x=155, y=420)

    b3 = Button(window, text="Another One", font="times 13", bg="#ffc003", width=12, command=game)
    b3.place(x=265, y=420)

    start = timer()

    window.mainloop()

x1 = Label(root, text="Let's test your typing speed!", bg="black", fg="white", font="times 15")
x1.place(x=100,y=120)

b1 = Button(root, text="Go!", width=12, bg="#03fcf8", font="times 20", command=game)
b1.place(x=150, y=120)

hs_text = Label(root, text="Highscore", width=12, bg="#03fcf8", font="times 35")
hs_text.place(x=90,y=240)

hs = int(hs_file.readline())
hs_val = Label(root, txt= str(hs)+" WPM",width=12, fg="#03fcf8", bg="black", font="times 12")
hs_val.place(x=110, y=320)

root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: The option is `text`, not `txt`.

Answer (score 0):

In the line producing the error:

```
hs_val = Label(root, txt= str(hs)+" WPM",width=12, fg="#03fcf8", bg="black", font="times 12")
```

You write `txt=` to set the text, it should be `text=` so the new line should be:

```
hs_val = Label(root, text= str(hs)+" WPM",width=12, fg="#03fcf8", bg="black", font="times 12")
```

I can't double check to ensure all the issues are removed because I don't have the text file to test with but the full code should work like this:

```
hs_file = open('highscore.txt', '+r')
x=0

def game():
    global x
    if x==0:
        root.withdraw()
        x=x+1
    window.deiconify()
    def check_result():
        j=error=0
        answer=entry.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
        end = timer()
        time_taken=end-start
        
        if len(words[word])>=len(answer):
            error=len(words[word])-len(answer)
            for i in answer:
                if i == words[word]:
                    pass
                else:
                    error+=1
                j+=1
        elif len(words[word])<=len(answer):
            error=len(answer)-len(words[word])
            for i in words[word]:
                if i == answer[j]:
                    pass
                else:
                    error+=1
                j+=1
        wpm=len(answer)/5
        wpm= wpm-error
        wpm=int(wpm/(time_taken/60))
        hs_file.seek(0)
        line = int(hs_file.readline())
        if wpm>line:
            hs_file.seek(0)
            hs_file.write(str(wpm))
            result="Your Highscore is : "+str(wpm)+" WPM"
            messagebox.showinfo("Score", result)
        else:
            result="Your score is: "+str(wpm)+" WPM"
            messagebox.showinfo("Score",result)
    def finish():
        hs_file.close()
        window.destroy()
        root.destroy()
    
    words=["The world is beautiful.", "The kite is drastic."]
    word=random.randint(0, len(words)-1)

    x2= Label(window, text=words[word], bg='black', fg="white", height=7, width=47, font="times 15", wraplength=500)
    x2.place(x=15, y=10)

    x3=Button(window, text="Submit", font="times 20", bg="white", command=check_result)
    x3.place(x-220,y=350)

    entry = Text(window)
    entry.place(x=100, y=180, height=150, width=350)

    b2 = Button(window, text="Done", font="times 13", bg="#ffc003", width=12, command=finish)
    b2.place(x=155, y=420)

    b3 = Button(window, text="Another One", font="times 13", bg="#ffc003", width=12, command=game)
    b3.place(x=265, y=420)

    start = timer()

    window.mainloop()

x1 = Label(root, text="Let's test your typing speed!", bg="black", fg="white", font="times 15")
x1.place(x=100,y=120)

b1 = Button(root, text="Go!", width=12, bg="#03fcf8", font="times 20", command=game)
b1.place(x=150, y=120)

hs_text = Label(root, text="Highscore", width=12, bg="#03fcf8", font="times 35")
hs_text.place(x=90,y=240)

hs = int(hs_file.readline())
hs_val = Label(root, text= str(hs)+" WPM",width=12, fg="#03fcf8", bg="black", font="times 12")
hs_val.place(x=110, y=320)

root.mainloop()
```